# Postgresql extract last row for each id

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

Suppose I've next data

```
  id    date          another_info
  1     2014-02-01         kjkj
  1     2014-03-11         ajskj
  1     2014-05-13         kgfd
  2     2014-02-01         SADA
  3     2014-02-01         sfdg
  3     2014-06-12         fdsA
```

I want for each id extract last information:

```
  id    date          another_info
  1     2014-05-13         kgfd
  2     2014-02-01         SADA
  3     2014-06-12         fdsA
```

How could I manage that?

Answer (score 309, accepted):

The most efficient way is to use Postgres' `distinct on` operator

```
select distinct on (id) id, date, another_info
from the_table
order by id, date desc;
```

If you want a solution that works across databases (but is less efficient) you can use a window function:

```
select id, date, another_info
from (
  select id, date, another_info, 
         row_number() over (partition by id order by date desc) as rn
  from the_table
) t
where rn = 1
order by id;
```

The solution with a window function is in most cases faster than using a sub-query.

Comment: upvoted! it needs an index on date desc though, i always assumed indexes are searchable in both directions, an ascending default primary key index on date should work well for a descending on the same field, in my case i have composite keys (id, date) composite keys causing problems?

Comment: According to [the latest Postgres docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/indexes-ordering.html), indexes indeed work in both directions *unless* they are for more than one column and you flip the direction on some columns but not all. So an index on `date ASC` and `date DESC` will both work, but an index on `id ASC, date ASC` will not. You can either create an `id ASC, date DESC` index, or change your query to `ORDER BY id DESC, date DESC` to make it work with the `id ASC, date ASC` index.

Comment: It required me to double check that the first row according to the "order by" will be selected. So I found in the official documentation it will be indeed: "Note that the “first row” of each set is unpredictable unless ORDER BY is used to ensure that the desired row appears first"

Answer (score 30):

```
select * 
from bar 
where (id,date) in (select id,max(date) from bar group by id)
```

*Tested in PostgreSQL,MySQL*

Comment: This will give duplicate results if you have multiple rows with the same date for a single id

Comment: @Jorn good point, but I think the assumption here is that date is part of the primary key of the table since otherwise the whole grouping by id wouldn’t make much sense

Answer (score 7):

I found this as the fastest solution:

```sql
 SELECT t1.*
   FROM yourTable t1
     LEFT JOIN yourTable t2 ON t2.tag_id = t1.tag_id AND t2.value_time > t1.value_time
  WHERE t2.tag_id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 5):

**For most scenarios, The most efficient way is to use `GROUP BY`**

I saw the accepted answer which determine that using `distinct on (id) id` is The most efficient way to solve the problem which was described in the question but I believe it's extremely not accurate.
Sadly I couldn't find any helpfull insights from POSTGRES doc' but I did find  [this article](https://sqlperformance.com/2017/01/t-sql-queries/surprises-assumptions-group-by-distinct) which refference few others and provide examples whereas

> GROUP BY approach definitely leads to better performance

---

We had discussion over this subject at work and did a little experience over a table that holds some data about tags' blinks with 4,114,692 rows, and has indexes over tag_id and over timestamp (seperated indexes)

**Here are the queries:**

1.using ditinct:

```
select distinct on (tag_id) tag_id, timestamp, some_data 
from blinks 
order by id, timestamp desc;
```

2.using CTE + group by + join:

```
`with blink_last_timestamp as (
     select tag_id, max(timestamp) as max_timestamp
     from blinks 
     group by tag_id )
 select bl.tag_id, max_timestamp, some_data
 from blink_last_timestamp bl 
 join blinks b on 
     b.tag_id = bl.tag_id and 
     bd.timestamp = bl.max_timestamp`
```

The results where unambiguous and favored the second solution for this scenario (Which is pretty generic in my opinion),

showing that it is being 10X times (!) faster 1655.991 ms (00:01.656) vs 16723.346 ms (00:16.723) and of course delivered the same data.

Answer (score -8):

Group by id and use any aggregate functions to meet the criteria of last record. For example

```
select  id, max(date), another_info
from the_table
group by id, another_info
```

Comment: again this is will not give the actual output

Comment: What am i missing here?

Comment: You are distinguishing groups based on another_info, so this will not group solely by id. And if instead you use an aggregate function on another_info, to get correct grouping, then the aggregate function (say max()), won't return the another_info value for the row that has the max(date). Indeed, these two observations are the reason that this is a question in the first place.