# How to select last message send by some devices according to the device ID?

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, greatest-n-per-group

There is a messages table in my postgreSql DB. The table has names: deviceId, timestamp, message. 
deviceId is identical, it indicates the id of existing device.

```
deviceId         timestamp                      message
dev12345         2020-01-02 21:01:02            hello Jack
dev12229         2020-01-02 12:03:02            good
dev22245         2020-01-01 12:01:05            hello Mary
dev12345         2020-01-01 11:03:02            good morning
...              ...                            ...
```

Assume there are total 100 devices, each device has send many messages at different time. I want to select the last messages send by some devices. For example, the last messages send by `dev12345` and `dev22245`: `hello Jack` and `hello Mary`

Can you tell me how to do that using postgreSql command?

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28085468/postgresql-extract-last-row-for-each-id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Postgres, just use `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (deviceId) t.*
from mytable t
where device id in ('dev12345', 'dev22245')
order by deviceId, timestamp desc
```

The `distinct on (deviceId)` clause indicates the database that we just want one record per device; the `order by` clause controls which row is retained in each group (here, the sort gives the priority to the most recent record per device).

Answer (score 1):

You can use windows function (row_number)  and CTE combination:

```
WITH sub as (
select deviceId,message ,row_number() OVER (partition by deviceId  order by ts desc) as num  FROM tab )
SELECT deviceId,message FROM sub where num= 1
```