# Return all instances based on the max of an attribute of an associated model

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

Realise the title isn't well put at all. Essentially I have a model `TaskReferral` that has a `has_many` relationship with `TimeSlot`. I want to return all instances of TaskReferral that *do not* have any timeslots with a `started_at` past a given date

```
class MissionReferral < TaskReferral
  has_many :time_slots
end
```

```
class TimeSlot
  belongs_to :booking, polymorphic: true
end
```

I'm trying something like this in `mission_referral.rb:

```
scope :with_no_timeslots_after, lambda { |date|
    from(
      <<~SQL
        (
          SELECT *
          FROM task_referrals tr
          JOIN (
            SELECT booking_id, booking_type, max(started_at) as started_at
            FROM time_slots AS ts
            GROUP by booking_id, booking_type
          ) as latest_time_slot
          ON tr.id =  latest_time_slot.booking_id
          AND latest_time_slot.booking_type = 'TaskReferral'
          WHERE started_at < #{date.to_date}
        )
      SQL
    )
  }
```

But when I run `MissionReferral.with_no_timeslots_after(1.day.from_now)` I get:

```
MissionReferral Load (0.9ms)  SELECT "task_referrals".* FROM (
  SELECT *                                                                                                           
  FROM task_referrals tr                                                                                             
  JOIN (                                                                                                             
    SELECT booking_id, booking_type, max(started_at) as started_at                                                   
    FROM time_slots AS ts                                                                                            
    GROUP by booking_id, booking_type                                                                                
  ) as latest_time_slot                                                                                              
  ON tr.id =  latest_time_slot.booking_id                                                                            
  AND latest_time_slot.booking_type = 'TaskReferral'                                                                 
  WHERE started_at < 2023-09-16                                                                                      
)                                                                                                                    
 WHERE "task_referrals"."type" = $1  [["type", "MissionReferral"]]                                                   
(Object doesn't support #inspect)
```

Or if I run `MissionReferral.with_no_timeslots_after(1.day.from_now).count` I get:

```
MissionReferral Count (1.1ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (
  SELECT *                                                                                                           
  FROM task_referrals tr                                                                                             
  JOIN (                                                                                                             
    SELECT booking_id, booking_type, max(started_at) as started_at                                                   
    FROM time_slots AS ts                                                                                            
    GROUP by booking_id, booking_type                                                                                
  ) as latest_time_slot                                                                                              
  ON tr.id =  latest_time_slot.booking_id                                                                            
  AND latest_time_slot.booking_type = 'TaskReferral'                                                                 
  WHERE started_at < 2023-09-16                                                                                      
)                                                                                                                    
 WHERE "task_referrals"."type" = $1  [["type", "MissionReferral"]]                                                   
/home/dave-gg/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.4.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:768:in `exec_params': PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  subquery in FROM must have an alias (ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid)
LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (
                             ^
HINT:  For example, FROM (SELECT ...) [AS] foo.
/home/dave-gg/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.4.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:768:in `exec_params': ERROR:  subquery in FROM must have an alias (PG::SyntaxError)
LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (
                             ^
HINT:  For example, FROM (SELECT ...) [AS] foo.
```

Weirdly I can get the query to run in a SQL editor connected to the DB, so don't think I'm far off. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: That seems awkward. Seems like the following should work `TaskReferral.where(id: TimeSlot.where(booking_type: 'TaskReferral').select(:booking_id).group(:booking_id).having(TimeSlot.arel_table[:started_at].maximum.lt(date))))`

Comment: Please refer following posts https://stackoverflow.com/a/16918028/936494, https://stackoverflow.com/a/28085614/936494 if they can trigger any idea on achieving the desired results. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @engineersmnky that's exactly what I'm looking for. My querying skills aren't the greatest. If you want to put it as an answer I'll verify it